# Как сформировать запрос к игровому серверу?

Tags: node.js

Есть игровой сервер ETQW. Необходимо из него вытащить статистику текущей игры.
Нашел библиотеку  [gamedig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gamedig) , но она получает только общую информацию об игроках.
Никнайм, клантег, пинг и количество игроков/ботов.

Как нужно сформировать запрос на NodeJS, чтобы получить текущую статистику игры каждого игрока К/Д(убил/умер), и время игры до конца карты?

Статистику, примерно как на этой странице сервера https://www.gs4u.net/ru/s/147096.html

Сам код выглядит вот так:

```
const Gamedig = require('gamedig');
Gamedig.query({
    type: 'etqw',
    host: '178.162.135.83',
    port: '27735'
}).then((info) => {
    console.log(info);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Server is offline");
});
```

Ответ сервера такой:

```
Results {
  name: 'TAW|EU - how to connect: tiny.cc/etqw',
  map: 'canyon',
  password: false,
  raw: {
    protocolVersion: '10.21',
    si_version: 'ETQW 1.5.12663.12663  linux-x86 May  9 2008 13:47:37',
    net_serverPunkbusterEnabled: '0',
    net_serverDedicated: '1',
    si_teamForceBalance: '1',
    si_gameReviewReadyWait: '0',
    si_disableGlobalChat: '0',
    si_noProficiency: '0',
    si_allowLateJoin: '1',
    si_minPlayers: '1',
    si_readyPercent: '51',
    si_disableVoting: '0',
    si_adminStart: '0',
    si_motd_4: '1Gbps dedicated',
    si_motd_2: 'http://taw.net ',
    si_motd_1: 'TAW - The Art of Warfare ',
    si_adminname: 'FrodeThree',
    si_website: 'https://wiki.enemyterritory.org',
    si_timelimit: '20',
    si_rules: 'sdGameRulesCampaign',
    si_spectators: '1',
    si_pure: '1',
    si_needPass: '0',
    si_teamDamage: '1',
    si_privateClients: '0',
    si_maxPlayers: '32',
    si_name: 'TAW|EU - how to connect: tiny.cc/etqw',
    si_antiLagForgiving: '10',
    si_antiLagOnly: '1',
    si_antiLag: '1',
    bot_enable: '1',
    gamename: 'baseETQW-1',
    si_campaign: 'campaign_pacific',
    si_map: 'canyon',
    osmask: 7,
    ranked: 0,
    timeleft: 0,
    gamestate: 1,
    servertype: 0,
    interestedClients: 0
  },
  maxplayers: NaN,
  players: Players [],
  bots: Players [
    Player { name: 'CTZN Kane', raw: [Object] },
    Player { name: 'HaltHammerzeit', raw: [Object] },
    Player { name: 'Vlad_Putimir', raw: [Object] },
    Player { name: 'iceT-bag', raw: [Object] },
    Player { name: 'NoobMcBoob', raw: [Object] },
    Player { name: 'Boss_Tweed', raw: [Object] },
    Player { name: 'NiceLagSwitch', raw: [Object] },
    Player { name: 'FannyPack', raw: [Object] }
  ],
  connect: '178.162.135.83:27735',
  ping: 46
}
```

Comment: А что лежит в `results.raw.bots[0].raw`?

Comment: `results.bots[0].raw`
Там как раз и лежит  общая информация об игроке/боте   
`{ id: 0, ping: 0, clantag: '', typeflag: 1 }`
Пинг, клантег и положение клантега(сначала || в конце)

Comment: так там нет того, что вы ищете?

Comment: Нет.
Там общая информация об игроках. А статистики текущей игры там нет совсем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простого пути тут нет.

Читая [исходники](https://github.com/gamedig/node-gamedig/blob/ce4e72849386b5771959de7d6e024cf775090279/games.txt#L100) [gamedig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gamedig) понятно, что общение с сервером `Enemy Territory: Quake Wars` идёт по протоколу `doom3`.

> etqw|Enemy Territory: Quake Wars (2007)|doom3|port=3074,port_query=27733

А в модуле протокола `doom3` запрашивается только `getInfo`.

```
class Doom3 extends Core {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.encoding = 'latin1';
    }
    async run(state) {
        const body = await this.udpSend('\xff\xffgetInfo\x00PiNGPoNg\x00', packet => {
            ...
        });
    }
)
```

Чтобы попробовать запросить интересующую вас статистику, нужна хотя бы какая-то документация по протоколу `doom3`, список команд и интерпретация результатов.

Comment: спс. попробую порыть в том направении

Comment: я уже порыл, там есть getInfoEx. завтра напишу продолжение

Comment: собственно, задача: переложить на nodejs вот этот код https://github.com/jmp/etqw-server-query-library/blob/master/etqwlib.py. вот [отсюда](https://github.com/jmp/etqw-server-query-library/blob/6b344ac04f7df4266b41fb2547630fad288dc61b/etqwlib.py#L75) идёт разбор ваших убил/умер

Comment: Я вот как раз это и рою. Но getInfoEx ничего не возвращает.
Я  в самих исходниках эту строчку меняю.
Как бы увидеть весь текст который отдает сервер?
Тогда было бы легче рыться. Там только строка в Юникоде показывается в логах

Comment: Кстати та библиотека на Python у меня возвращает только 3 пустых объекта.
Но я в пайтон полный 0, может что-то не подключил...

Comment: Поставил Python  2 версии и библиотека заработала.

Comment: wireshark показывает что возвращается data разной длины, от запроса на python и от запроса на node.
python.length == 1179 bytes
node.length == 1025 bytes
и визуально видно что в версии python есть дополнительные данные. Например команда игрока

Comment: в gamedig используется обращение к `getInfo`, в etqwlib.py - к `getInfoEx`. `getInfoEx` возвращает больше данных

Comment: Да все так и есть. Заменил запрос и получил больше данных. 1176 bytes(1179 это я ошибся когда писал выше)
Теперь буду рыться как их прочитать. 
Спс еще раз.